# Callback confusion fs module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I currently wrote this script to run in node:

```
console.log('Node starting...');
var fs = require('fs');
fs.readFile('./app.js', function(err, data){
    // if(err) throw err;
    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

I understand the function being passed to readFile(file, callback(err, data) is a callback function and it will be executed when it receives the data parameter.

My problem is, I am clueless on what is actually passing this function the data?

The documentation states

> The callback is passed two arguments (err, data), where data is the
>   contents of the file.

What is actually passing the callback function the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `fs.readFile` function gets the data and then calls the callback function with the data as an argument.

You could write such a function yourself (and, in fact, you'll probably do it a lot as you use Node.js more) like this:

```
function readFile(filename, callbackFunction) {
  var data;

  // ...do some work to get the data...

  if(somethingBadHappened) {
    callbackFunction("An error occurred!")
    return;
  }

  // success!
  callbackFunction(null, data);
}
```

And you'd use it just like you do `fs.readFile`:

```
function myCallback(err, data) {
  console.log( data.toString() );
}

readFile( './myfile.txt', myCallback );
```

If you want, you can read the [actual source of fs.readFile](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/c7f424e44b7e61b89f91cd344599c3d1cdfb88fe/lib/fs.js#L205-L294). It's quite short (but a little more complicated than my example)!